# Android Studio - Gradle settings

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm new to Android Studio and I built a project from Github with an included gradle.properties file.

If I hover over "org.gradle.jvmargs=[...]" it says "Unused property". A comment in gradle.properties says

> IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users: Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override* any settings specified in this file.

How can I configure Gradle in Android Studio?

I found older guides where you could add command line arguments under setting. But this option is missing. (Android Studio 2.1.2)

[image: Settings - Gradle]
Edit: "Unused property" is probably a bug. I'm pretty sure it's using the gradle.properties file in the project. I decided to create a gradle.properties file in USER_HOME/.gradle instead of using command line arguments. It also shows up in Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Settings dialog, look instead under `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Compiler` - there's a `Command-line options` box there - I think that is where you override settings now. It's empty by default though so unless you've set something there, it wouldn't be overriding other settings. It's a per-project setting - you can also change your defaults for all projects by editing user settings files - described here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You can search in the preferences window for "Command-line" (Note: this is IntelliJ IDEA, but should be similar in Android Studio)

[image: Gradle CMD]